# Leaving trail of a vehicle in google maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am developing an application with google maps API and I want to add a functionality that leaves the trail of te path covered by the vehicle. Can anyone suggest me an efficient function or method to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using a [polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459762/leaving-trail-of-a-vehicle-in-google-maps-api) and then adding points to it as the vehicle's position updates.

As a note, remember to look at the Terms of Service under the section Asset tracking to make sure you are complying.

Comment: Thank you!! I am just animating on the map